# Exporting code for definitions with the universal quantifier in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, quantifiers

I’m trying to export code from the Isabelle theorem prover using its code extraction tools. The code I’m trying to extract is based on an integrity constraint that returns a boolean value from a record made up of sets of two different types, plus a set of pairs of these types, like this:

```
typedecl type_a
typedecl type_b
```

```
record my_record =
    aset :: "type_a set"
    bset :: "type_b set"
    pair :: "(type_a × type_b) set"
```

```
definition constraint :: "my_record ⇒ bool" where"
    constraint rcd = (∀ a b. (a, b) ∈ pair rcd ⟶ (a ∈ aset rcd ∧ b ∈ bset rcd))"
```

Here is where I try to extract the code to Haskell and SML files:

```
export_code constraint
    in SML module_name SML_constraint
    in Haskell module_name haskell_constraint
```

But when doing so, I get a wellsortedness error, which I think is caused by the type I used not being enumerable? Here’s what it looks like:

```
Wellsortedness error
(in code equation constraint ?rcd ≡ 
    ∀a b. (a, b) ∈ pair ?rcd ⟶ a ∈ aset ?rcd ∧ b ∈ bset ?rcd):
Type type_a not of sort enum
No type arity type_a :: enum
```

Notably, the problem goes away if I replace the `type_a` and `type_b` types with natural numbers and define a limited value range for them in the constraint, e.g. a maximum of 100:

```
record my_record =
    aset :: "nat set"
    bset :: "nat set"
    pair :: "(nat × nat) set"
```

```
definition constraint :: "my_record ⇒ bool" where
    "constraint rcd = (∀ a < 100. ∀ b < 100. (a, b) ∈ pair rcd ⟶ (a ∈ aset rcd ∧ b ∈ bset rcd))"
```

For this, the code export works. However, I need to use the abstract types I defined before. Is there a way I can somehow enumerate these types so the error doesn’t occur, or maybe define the constraint in a different way that doesn’t require the ∀ quantifier (which seems to be the cause of the error) but its meaning remains the same?

Comment: Does something like this work? `definition constraint :: "my_record ⇒ bool" where"
    constraint rcd = (∀ab ∈ pair rcd. (fst ab ∈ aset rcd ∧ snd ab ∈ bset rcd))"
`

Comment: At the very end, the issue is that Isabelle supports only terminating function and `∀a. P a` is not terminating without restrictions on P or on the type of a (like: can be enumerated).

Comment: Ah no, my proposition does not work either, because by default equality cannot be computer either.